# Set an ID on a browser instance with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I am connecting to a remote browser instance as follows:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: webSocket });
```

At the remote node, I am maintaining a pool of browsers, so the above could be attaching to any one of those.  The `webSocket` above isn't for a specific browser from the pool... it is a fixed websocket address for the remote node, and at the remote node I am proxying the request to one of the browsers in the pool.

Mainly for debugging/tracing purposes, is there any way to assign an ID to each browser instance at the remote node, which can be read from the `browser` (above) at the local node, so that I can see (at the local node) which one of the remote browsers has been assigned?

I thought about setting the `User-Agent` of the `browser` (when it is created at the remote node, which would be readable back at the local node), but it seems that this can only be set at the `page` level, not `browser` level.